Issue with .animation in SwiftUI causing the entire view to move
I am having an issue after updating to Xcode 15 where my view unexpectedly moves when trying to animate a rotating Circle() in SwiftUI. Previously, this code worked perfectly, but now the entire view either shifts from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner continuously or, in some cases, just the Circle() moves unexpectedly.
The problem seems to occur when the animation is added. If I remove the animation code, the Circle() remains fixed and displays correctly.
Here is the code I am using to display the rotating circle:
Circle()     
.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 7, lineCap: .round, dash: [10, 30]))     
.frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)     
.foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)     
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 0 : 360.0))     
.onAppear {         
    isLoading = true     
}     
.animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isLoading) 

When the animation is applied, the view starts moving as described. However, without the animation, everything works fine.
Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?
Environment:
Xcode 15
macOS (SwiftUI project)
Already tried this , but same result
  .onAppear(perform: {                     
              withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses:false)){                    
        isLoading.toggle()                     
        }                 
    })                 
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 0 : 360.0))


Do you mean after updating to Xcode 16? Can you provide a recording of your issue and maybe more complete  reproducible code? If I try this, after adding the missing isLoading state in a new view, the circle seems to rotate just fine.

Are the tags correct? I was able to reproduce on macOS, but not iOS.

I was able to reproduce the issue running on Mac Sequoia 15.0.1 with Xcode 16.0. It may be another case of a launch animation getting tangled with other animations when the view appears, see also:

SwiftUI unexpected position changes during animation
Why does an animation in a NavigationView starts from the top left corner?
SwiftUI: Broken explicit animations in NavigationView?

Here are three workarounds, none of which I can really explain, but they seem to fix the issue:

Change the order of the modifiers so that the .rotationEffect comes before .frame:

Circle()
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 7, lineCap: .round, dash: [10, 30]))
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 0 : 360.0))
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
    .onAppear {
        isLoading = true
    }
    .animation(.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isLoading)


Remove the .animation modifier and set the flag using withAnimation instead.

Circle()
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 7, lineCap: .round, dash: [10, 30]))
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 0 : 360.0))
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
            isLoading = true
        }
    }


Set the flag using .task, instead of in .onAppear:

Circle()
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 7, lineCap: .round, dash: [10, 30]))
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    .foregroundStyle(Color.accentColor)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 0 : 360.0))
    .task { @MainActor in
        isLoading = true
    }
    .animation(.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isLoading)


Thank you for sharing your possible solutions. I tried all of them, and the third solution is working perfectly. I also discovered that if I execute the animation on the main thread like this:
DispatchQueue.main.async {     withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {         isLoading = true     } }
It works flawlessly.
Is putting it on the main thread a good approach, or should I handle it differently? Any advice would be appreciated!

@JawadSaud Using DispatchQueue is the same as solution 3, but it's the old way to run a task. I would suggest, .task is the preferred way. Also, you only need to wrap it withAnimation if you are not using an .animation modifier. Ps. thanks for accepting the answer!

Thank you for your help; I really appreciate your time and effort.
